# Add arbitrarly positioned button to a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, storyboard

I have a UITableViewController to which I want to add a button at the bottom right corner of. The button would stay there as you scroll and just be in front of the table view.

How would I add a button like this? I've tried adding a transparent subview with the button but the only thing it changes is removing the separators of my tableview (heres how I tried it, I added this to the `viewDidLoad`)

```
let transparentView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
transparentView.alpha = 0

let plusButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50))
plusButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "plus")
transparentView.addSubview(plusButton)
self.view.addSubview(transparentView)
```

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard, you can add the button above the UITableView, and position it with constraints. You can set an image and all that stuff there.

If you need to do it in code, then just add the button as a subview to your UITableViewController. If you put it in another view and set the alpha to 0 then the button disappears with it's superview. You can use something like [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout) to keep it in the corner.

```
let plusButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50))
plusButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "plus")
self.view.addSubview(plusButton)
plusButton.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(ALEdge.Right, withInset: 8)
plusButton.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(ALEdge.Bottom, withInset: 8)
```

Comment: I'm trying to add it using the storyboard, by just dragging a button onto the tableVC, but it gets moved to right underneath my last prototype table view cell. [here's](http://tinypic.com/r/m9rker/8) a video

Comment: So move it up in the hierarchy on the left